# Class diagram editor

Tags: uml, tool-uml

I have a file very big file .umlclass. It has a lot of classes, Enumerationtypes, relations.... I want to organize it in the class diagram Editor, but it is impossible because I don't know where the things are.

In the Project Explorer of Eclipse I can see the tree and in the view properties I can see the properties of each one, but I can't see it in the class diagram Editor.

Is there any kind of select or find each resource in the diagram Editor? I'm using the UML2Tools plugin.

Thanks in advance.

Ramón.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the UML2Tools don't have a full fledged editor. Consider using another editor for your Eclipse UML2 Model.

Answer (score 0):

Omondo EclipseUML can read all UML2Tools model.

You just need to to create an empty class diagram and drag and drop one classifier inside the diagram. The project will immediately import all models and then allow you to navigate graphically in the model using the class diagram as a viewer of your model.
It is really good because your diagrams are not anymore the model itself as it is for many tools but only a viewer of your model.
Really cool feature :-)